# How to read json response using jsonArray in java code

Tags: arrays, json, httpclient

I have a query, I have to read key "class" under key"studentData" from the below mentioned json response.
{

"studentData": [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "class": 2,
      "rollno": "2015"
    }
  ],
  "yearofenrollment": 2017
  }

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObjectResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString()); //obtain the object
JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonObjectResponse.optJSONArray("studentData");//get array from object
JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(0);//get first object in array
String studentDataValue = jsonChildNode.optString("class");//obtain value from class key
```